# What is a white spot with a black dot on my peppermint?

Tags: diseases, leaves, mint

These spots began to appear on the leaves of my peppermint, what could it be?

[image: Peppermint leaf]

The other side of the leaves looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably leaf miner damage - the black part is likely the entry/exit point. Either that or something's dropped onto the leaves - anything interesting on the underside of the leaves?

Comment: Nothing ununsual in the underside of the leaves.. I put a picture in the question. Thank you for the help!